# My globe keys gone

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

My younger sister plays with my iphone4 and at one point I thought I had a globe key and realized I don't. How can I get it back or is there a way to get one for my phone?

Answer (score 4):

Probably she's deactivated a keyboard that you had previously activated. If you want to get it back, go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> International Keyboards and add whichever you need.